# unable to view/access HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Last night I installed 18.04 on a new computer with a 250GB SSD at sda and a 6TB HDD at sdb.   I formatted the SSD as 35MB EFI, 3.1GB for /boot. 133GB for /home, 72GB  as /, 38GB as /var.    The HDD was formatted as 36MB as EFI, 16GB as /swap.  The balance of the drive was formatted as /usr.   All are using EXT4 except for the swap partition.    I am unable to access or create folders in the /usr folder.

As I have not done or installed any extras in this system as yet, as I better off to reinstall and create the swap on the HDD and the balance of the HDD as /home and not put the home partition on the SSD.

What or how would you partition such a system?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do such complicated partitioning for sure.

You don't need separated `/boot`, `/var`, `/usr` and certainly not a second EFI partition in the HDD.

A case can be made for a separated `/home` but that's it.

Personally I wouldn't care about that at all and simply use the HDD for data (personal files) storage only, with everything else in the SSD.

And with 18.04 you don't need to create a `swap` partition either.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr` is normally root-owned so it's normal you cannot write to that with your normal user. user space is normally in `/home/<username>` and it's the only place you have write access to, by default.
Reinstalling system won't help because this is by design.